# how to remove NaN from numpy subarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have following numpy array:

```
array([['0.0', '0.0'],
       ['3.0', '0.0'],
       ['3.5', '35000.0'],
       ['4.0', '70000.0'],
       ['4.2', 'nan'],
       ['4.5', '117000.0'],
       ['5.0', '165000.0'],
       ['5.2', 'nan'],
       ['5.5', '225000.0'],
       ['6.0', '285000.0'],
       ['6.2', 'nan'],
       ['6.5', '372000.0'],
       ['7.0', '459000.0'],
       ['7.5', '580000.0'],
       ['8.0', '701000.0'],
       ['8.1', 'nan'],
       ['8.5', '832000.0'],
       ['8.8', 'nan'],
       ['9.0', '964000.0'],
       ['9.5', '1127000.0'],
       ['33.0', 'nan'],
       ['35.0', 'nan']], dtype='<U12')
```

I want to drop all subarrays with nan values.

Desired output is:

```
array([['0.0', '0.0'],
       ['3.0', '0.0'],
       ['3.5', '35000.0'],
       ['4.0', '70000.0'],
       ['4.5', '117000.0'],
       ['5.0', '165000.0'],
       ['5.5', '225000.0'],
       ['6.0', '285000.0'],
       ['6.5', '372000.0'],
       ['7.0', '459000.0'],
       ['7.5', '580000.0'],
       ['8.0', '701000.0'],
       ['8.5', '832000.0'],
       ['9.0', '964000.0'],
       ['9.5', '1127000.0'], dtype='<U12')
```

I ended with trying with `np.isnan(array)` , but I got error `ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types` . One idea while writing this is to split array in two arrays and get nan indexes and apply filter on both arrays and merge back. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Right -- `NaN` is a scalar, and does not compare to an array.  Instead, you have to check the second element of each array.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for some reason, the provided array is an array of strings. So before proceeding further we need to convert it to an array of floats:

```
# assuming your original array is arr
new_arr = arr.astype(float)
```

Then, we can filter the list elements, in a way to only keep the subarrays which second element is not `NaN`

```
filtered_list = np.array(list(filter(lambda x: not np.isnan(x[1]), new_arr)))
```

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

```py
a = a.astype(float); filtered = a[~np.isnan(a[:, 1])]
```

Assuming you want your numpy array as floats and not strings:

```py
import numpy as np


# generate similar data
a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=20, size=(5, 2)).astype(str)
a[[0, 2, 3], 1] = 'nan'
print(a)
# [['15' 'nan']
#  ['17' '9']
#  ['15' 'nan']
#  ['5' 'nan']
#  ['14' '14']]

# convert to float first
a = a.astype(float)

# filter by np.nan
filtered = a[~np.isnan(a[:, 1])]

print(filtered)
# [[17.  9.]
#  [14. 14.]]
```